# Derived category of $k$-vector spaces

Tags: derived-categories

Let $k$  be a  field.  How  can   describe  the  morphisms  in  the  derived  categories  of  $k$-vector  spaces? I  know   that  every  short  exact  sequence   is   splitting.

Comment: Take the definition of the morphisms in an arbitrary derived category associated to an abelian category (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_category) and specialize to the case of the category of vector spaces over a field $k$. Note: One can choose in each isomorphism class of an object a special representative... But this is an other question.

Answer (score 10):

Dan Petersen's answer is excellent, I am just providing more details. You can easily check that any complex of vector spaces is the direct sum of the two following complexes (with arbitrary degrees of course) :

$$ \dots \to 0 \to k \to 0 \to \dots $$

$$ \dots 0 \to k \overset{id}{\to} k \to 0 \to \dots$$

The second complex is obviously quasi isomorphic to the zero complex. This shows that any $V \in D$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_{i \in \Bbb Z} V^i[i]$ for some vector spaces $V^i$.

Now $Hom_D(k,k[j]) = Ext^j_k(k,k) = 0$ if $j \neq 0$, and $k$ else. So it follows that $Hom_D(V,W) = \oplus_{i \in \Bbb Z}(Hom_k(V^i, W^i))$ which is by definition $Hom(V,W)$ in the category of graded vector spaces. Again, as Dan Petersen said, you can apply exactly the same argument to any semisimple abelian category.

Comment: $V^i[i]$  is  the  same  $i$?

Comment: @rafa : yes. $V^i$ is by definition a vector space, and also by abuse of notation is a complex concentrated in degree $0$. For a complex $K$, we define $K[i]^n := K^{i+n}$ (with differential multiplied by $(-1)^i$). I hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 4):

The derived category in question is equivalent to the category of graded $k$-vector spaces. In fact this is true generally for the derived category of a semisimple abelian category.

Comment: Your answer is excellent (+1), I just did another answer with more precisions, I hope you don't mind.